# How to filter SSE script for duplicate messages?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, server-sent-events

There seems to be a strange bug within a Server-sent Event implementation I've created. The problem seems to lie within on the client-side through a filtering system. The issue is that the script is supposed to only update the application data stream when there is new info, instead of just continuously repeating everything. Currently, the script stops the stream from repeating everything but the last message received. This last message is the only one to repeat indefinitely.

I tried to filter the messages on the server side as well but it seems to no avail. Any info I left out, just ask and I'd be more than happy to supply you with it.

Client-side Javascript

```
function getMsgs() {
    if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource('');
        var last_id;
        var used = {};
        source.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.origin != 'http://example.com') {
                alert('Error: Unidentified origin!');
                return;
            } else {
                var now_id = event.lastEventId;
                if (window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 800px)").matches) {
                    if (last_id != now_id && document.getElementById('content').innerHTML != event.data) {
                        last_id = event.lastEventId;
                        if (!used[event.data]) {
                            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += event.data;
                            used[event.data] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (last_id != now_id && document.getElementById('chatMsgs').innerHTML != event.data) {
                        last_id = event.lastEventId;
                        if (!used[event.data]) {
                            document.getElementById('chatMsgs').innerHTML += event.data;
                            used[event.data] = 1;
                            document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat').scrollHeight; //keep scrollbar at the bottom
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
```

Server side PHP

*The `lstMsg` session is previously set when the user logs in

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
include "../includes/config.php"; 
include "../includes/functions.php";
function getMessages($time) {
    $con = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);   
    $con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
    $getLastMsg = "SELECT MAX(`sent`) FROM `messages` WHERE `msg_to` = '$_SESSION[username]' AND `type` = '0' LIMIT 1";
    $retrieveTime = $con->query($getLastMsg);
    $_SESSION['lstMsg'] = $retrieveTime->fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $getMsgs = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `msg_to` = '$_SESSION[username]' AND `type` = '0' AND `sent` > '$time' ORDER BY `sent` ASC";
    $receivedMsgs = $con->query($getMsgs); 
    foreach ($receivedMsgs->fetchAll() as $msg) { 
        $getUI = "SELECT `profile_pic`, `full_name`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$msg[msg_from]'";
        $uiQuery = $con->query($getUI);
        while ($UI = $uiQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
            echo "id: {$msg['id']}\n"; 
            echo "data: <article class='post'>\n"; 
            echo "data: <img src='{$UI[profile_pic]}' alt='{$UI[full_name]}' />\n"; 
            echo "data: <section class='pContainer'>\n";
            echo "data: <p class='timeAgo'>". Agotime($msg[sent]) ."</p>\n"; 
            echo "data: <a style='position:absolute;' href='/profile?uid={$UI[username]}'>{$UI['full_name']}</a><br />\n"; 
            echo "data: <h4>@{$msg['msg_from']}</h4>\n"; 
            echo "data: <p class='postContent'>{$msg['message']}</p>\n"; 
            echo "data: </section>\n"; 
            echo "data: </article>\n\n"; 
        } 
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
    }
}
getMessages($_SESSION['lstMsg']);
?>
```

Comment: After checking the data stream directly, I can confirm it isn't repeating any data whatsoever. The stream itself seems to be fine.

Comment: Might it have something to do with being declared inside a function?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Inside or outside the scope of the function doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: ...and how about defining your server side script in `new EventSource('');`?

Comment: It is defined. I removed it on here for privacy reasons.

Comment: Cool - I'm going to keep an eye on this, interesting problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and finally found the way to stop the last message (from server) from repeating.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` > '$_SESSION["id"]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row["data_from_database"];
            if($_SESSION["id"] < $row["id"]){
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
        }
}
```

But, you must set the $_SESSION["id"] variable at the page, which is establishing (calling) the connection for SSE, otherwise it won't work.